# ggplot boxplot on log scale, mean via stat_summary appears wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm generating boxplots for right skewed data, so using a log scale.  The boxplots themselves are fine, but if I add means to the boxplots via `stat_summary`, they appear to be incorrect.  Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Reproducible example below.  The problem is obvious if we note that for group B, the mean exceeds the 3rd quartile, and yet the red dot is inside the box...

```
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tmp <- data.frame(x = c(rlnorm(100, 11, 1), rlnorm(100, 10, 2)),
                  gp = c(rep("A",100), rep("B",100))) 
by(tmp$x, tmp$gp, mystat<-function(x){c(mean(x),quantile(x, c(0,.25,.5,.75,1)))})

ggplot(aes(x=gp, y=x), data = tmp) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point") + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma)
```

Comment: This is an easy enough work around, but I'd be interested in understanding what stat_summary is doing and why.  

`meandf <- data.frame(gp = c("A", "B"), m = c(mean(tmp$x[tmp$gp=="A"]), mean(tmp$x[tmp$gp=="B"])))
ggplot(aes(x=gp, y=x), data = tmp) + geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x =  gp, y = m), data = meandf, color = "red") + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! The answer is simply the order of operations: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387824/r-ggplot2-using-stat-summary-mean-and-logaritmic-scale). I've checked that the answer there works for your case.