# Issue with logscale plot using geom_violin in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an issue in plotting the violin plot for a dataset. I have used ggplot2 for this purpose. The violin plot itself looks ok, but the mean value for each bean is placed consistently below where they actually should appear. All the data points are numeric ranging 0-1.

Here is a reproducible code in R:

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(1, 100), y = runif(100, min=0, max=1))

d <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_violin()
d +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.1), trans = "log10")
```

If you look at the plot, you will see the mean value marked at ~ 0.4 while the actual mean is 0.49.

[image: plot produced by the code]

Comment: Can you add reproducible sample data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R ggplot2: using stat\_summary (mean) and logarithmic scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387824/r-ggplot2-using-stat-summary-mean-and-logarithmic-scale)

Comment: I had the same issue. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753628/ggplot-boxplot-length-of-whiskers-with-logarithmic-axis/38757310#38757310).